# Windows 7 detects my motherboard but no display, no mouse & no keyboard were detected

Tags: windows-7, motherboard

My machine has Intel DH61CR motherboard, motherboard is blinking, CPU fan is also working but display is not coming to life.

I have troubleshoot the basic things; replaced RAM, replaced all cables, and even SMPS also, but got no positive response.

I'm confused, what to do next?

Comment: did you plug in the CPU power connector?

Answer (score 0):

---

1. Try testing to change your ram slot . Then try with no ram and
   you should get three beeps for no RAM error. Does it beep at all
   when you power it up?

---

2. Also you should check the cpu to see there is any sign of physical
   damage like burn marker. If the answer is no then the MotherBoard is dead.